# one to optional one relationship in EclipseLink

Tags: java, persistence, eclipselink

I've database where I'm joining tables O...1 that is one to optional one.

What tag should I use in persistence Entity class @OneToOne or @OneToMany relationship?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@OneToOne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) is what you're looking for. Its optional attribute is used to tell if its a 1-0..1 or a 1-1. By default, `optional` is true, so it means that it's a 1-0..1.

Comment: But then do I have to be careful  because I can have NullPointer when I'm trying to get value that is not there if you see what i mean.

Comment: Yes, of course. Since the field is nullable, you have to check for null before calling any method on it.

Comment: So is not just easier to do @OneToMany and for loop will prevent from executing method on nullable. For example for(Object o: objectsList){ o.getId }. Where object list will be 0 in size as there is no value. Is that practical ??

Comment: No it's not. If you have a OneToOne, use a OneToOne.